# Jquery slider in reverse order

Tags: jquery, slider, reverse

This is code of jquery image slider

http://jsfiddle.net/6pLg5/

```
$(".Slider > div:gt(0)").hide();

function slideLoop() {
  $('.Slider > div:first')
  .next()
  .show()
  .end()
  .appendTo('.Slider');
}

slideLoop();

setInterval(slideLoop, 3000);

$('.right').click(
    slideLoop
)
```

I'm making control buttons. Slide right is works. How to make slide left function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show it in fiddle?

Comment: Sure. http://jsfiddle.net/6pLg5/

Comment: do you want same like this or any other method?

Comment: May any other method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

HTML code

```
<div id="img-grp-wrap">
    <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="http://www.pictures-of-cats.org/images/ragdoll-cat-small-pictures-of-cats.jpg" />
        <img src="http://0.tqn.com/d/paganwiccan/1/G/T/1/-/-/BlackCat.jpg" />
        <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-H_iTYn3QQOk/Tfp5aK2vi5I/AAAAAAAAABM/QM45bNOM4HY/s1600/cat-claw.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.pictures-of-cats.org/images/Pixiebob-cat-list-of-cat-breeds-pictures-of-cats.jpg" />
    </div>    
    <img src="http://annhowardesign.com/images/arrowright.jpg" class="next" alt="Next"/> 
    <img src="http://annhowardesign.com/images/arrowleft.jpg" class="prev" alt="Previous"/>     
</div>
```

CSS...

```
#img-grp-wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.img-wrap {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
}

.img-wrap img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
}

.next, .prev {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 70px;
}

.next {
    right: -40px;
}

.prev {
    left: -40px;
}
```

Jquery...

```
$('.img-wrap img:gt(0)').hide();

$('.next').click(function() {
    $('.img-wrap img:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.img-wrap');
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
    $('.img-wrap img:first-child').fadeOut();
    $('.img-wrap img:last-child').prependTo('.img-wrap').fadeOut();
    $('.img-wrap img:first-child').fadeIn();
});
```

Finally the working fiddle is.... http://jsfiddle.net/b4T7m/

If you need with setInterval... http://jsfiddle.net/bh6aY/

Enjoy your coding....!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the function.

```
function reverseLoop() {
  $('.Slider > div:last')
  .addClass('animation')
  .prev()
  .removeClass('animation')
  .show()
  .end()
  .appendTo('.Slider');
}

setInterval(reverseLoop, 8000);
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but it's not works..
This is jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/6pLg5/
I added buttons. Slide right is works, slide left not..